# tags and getTags() are throwing error in cucumber-report-generator freemarker template

Tags: cucumber, freemarker

I am generating cucumber run results using mkolisnyk cucumber-report-generator and freemarker templates. I am able to display the featureName, status, duration etc but not tag names. The below is the template snippet in my template file

```
<#list features as feature>
    <td>${feature.featureName}</td>
    <td>${feature.status}</td>
    <td>${feature.duration}</td>
</#list>
```

But `<td>${feature.tag}</td>` is throwing error

> FreeMarker template error:
>   The following has evaluated to null or missing:
>   ==> feature.tags  [in template "overview" at line 173, column 23]

I tried the below ways also, but still i am getting same error.

```
<td>${feature.tag}</td>
<td>${feature.getTags()}</td>
<td>${feature.getTags()[0]}</td>
<td>${feature.getTags().name}</td>
<td>${feature.getTags()[0].name}</td>
```

`<td>${feature}</td>` returns no error but value as `com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.reporting.types.beans.OverviewDataBean$FeatureStatusRow@bcb09a6`

Please help me out in resolving the issue.

Comment: Either `getTag()` returns `null`, or there's no public `getTag()` method. (You can try the last as `Has getTag: ${feature.getTag???c}`) Also, why are you trying `getTags()` later on, which is in plural? And what error does that give?

Comment: @ddekany I have checked the documentation and there is ``` getTags() ``` method along with featureName and duration.  The feature file has multiple tags and the method available is getTags() which returns string array.

Comment: So then with what error message does `${feature.tags?join(', ')}` fail (if it does)? If the problem is that `getTags()` sometimes returns `null`, what do you want to display in that case? Like if nothing,  then you can write `${feature.tags!?join(', ')}` (note the `!`)